# Goods reads about Herakles/Hercules twelve labors?

Tags: greek, hercules, source-request

I would like to read more about Herakles twelve labors.

I would like to know if there are any remaining work about it ?
I am looking for work dating from the Greek or Roman era.

Comment: Removed the meta-commentary. I don't think this is too broad or _primarily_ opinion based. The question explicitly asks for ancient sources, and there's simply not that many for this to turn into a crapfest where everyone posts their favourite (which is what the close reasons are meant to protect as from). Everyone is - of course - free to vote to close this if they feel differently, but I think it's a good question for the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for a summary of what the ancient poets wrote about, your best bet would be to look at Pseudo-Apollodorus' [*Bibliotecha*](http://www.theoi.com/Text/Apollodorus2.html#5). The *Bibliotecha* is a work that collates nearly all of Greek mythology into a single, coherent narrative, including the Labors of Heracles.

If you want an even quicker summary, there's also Hyginus' [*Fabulae*](http://www.theoi.com/Text/HyginusFabulae1.html#30), but you'll notice a major difference in length!

If you're looking for something comparable to the *Iliad* or *Odyssey*, I'm afraid you'll be at a lost, as none of the epics about Heracles' labors survived. That said, if you check out the [Theoi](http://www.theoi.com/greek-mythology/heracles.html) page on Heracles' labors, you'll find a hefty collection of allusions and references about them scattered throughout extant Greek and Roman works.

Comment: Great point about lost Herculean epics.